# DisplayTag export to excel with Search Conditions conditions on the Top of the Table

Tags: java, struts, displaytag

I am Using Struts2 and DisplayTag for my application. I have requirement to export the table results into excel including the following two more functionalities.
1.Have to export all the records of search Criteria(i have pagination.so at a time i am showing only 20 records).
2.Have to append the Filter conditions into Excel.

Is it possible to have Custom decorator from where i can add the Filter Conditions into Excel before export.

some sample which code i am using,

```
<display:table id="data" name="lstEntities"
                        sort="external" uid="row" htmlId="rowid" class="tborder"
                        excludedParams="*" style="width:100%"
                        pagesize="${pageCriteria.recordsPerPage}" partialList="true"
                        size="${pageCriteria.totalRecords}" export="false"
                        requestURI="planningItemListMDA.action">
                        <display:column property="planningIrc" sortName="planningIrc"
                            sortable="true" titleKey="table.title.planningIrc"
                            style="width:100px" />.....
```

Thanks in advance.